# Oracle deadlocks for two uncommon queries

Tags: database, oracle, deadlock

I have dead lock: sql A is waiting on sql B.

---

----- Information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----

A is: `delete from attachment where ID=:1`

---

----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=audwbsf163w1n) -----

B is: `delete from detail where ID=:1`

---

[deadlock trace log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4JVY.png)

---

**My big question is**. Why is possible that these two sql scripts are waiting on each other but they have nothing in common in database? It do not make any sense, that they are waiting on each other.

Comment: You need to add more details regarding the tables: is there a connection between those 2 tables, meaning foreign keys or similar?

Comment: Table definition please

Comment: Please post the complete trace file.

Comment: i can not give you full table definition, but i can sure you that there is not connection between those 2 tables, no foreign keys, nothing

Comment: complete tracel file have 20000 lines.

Comment: Check the trace file for the objects involved in the deadlock.  The deadlock could be happening on a parent table, bitmap index, etc.  The trace file should have all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise care with the terminology used: "Deadlock" has a very specific meaning (below) and what you are implying in your problem description is a "blocking lock".

A deadlock is the classic “deadly embrace” problem.  The “deadly embrace” happens when, say Task B, attempts to lock a row which is being held by another task, say Task A, and Task A is waiting for Task B to release a lock.  Oracle will abort one of the transaction to prevent a perpetual wait condition.

Root Cause (general): 
•  Transactions deadlocked one another while waiting for resources. [from ora docs]

General Solution:
•  Generally, this is a design flaw in the application.
•  The deadlock is an application issue and must be fixed within the application; 
there is no DB fix  for a deadlock.

A deadlock will result in Oracle terminating one of the sessions and that session will receive an error indicating the reason. This happens with 2 to 3 seconds of it being detected.

A blocking lock on the other hand will remain indefinitely until the blocking session either commits, is rolled-back or is killed (which does a rollback).

Also, check for cascading operations generated as recursive SQL by the DBMS.

Comment: *** 2017-05-17 14:28:47.262
DEADLOCK DETECTED ( ORA-00060 )
 
[Transaction Deadlock]
 
The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a
deadlock due to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:

Comment: application is running on 4 computer, what shoud i do in my application to prevent deadlocks? it is a java application

Comment: check for cascading operations generated as recursive SQL by the DBMS.As a workaround you may want to consider single threading the application to prevent multiple sessions from updating the same row at the same time.